# Memory consequences for an anonymous class

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a code like below

```
class XXX {
    private Date date = new Date();    

    public void doSomething() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do a long running operation and use the date variable
            }
        }).start();
     }

}
```

I have an instance of the XXX class and I call doSomething() on it. No other code is referencing the XXX instance anymore.

My question is: while the started thread is running, is the GC allowed to remove XXX instance from the heap? Is the GC allowed to remove the date instance from the heap?

As far as I know when an anonymous class uses a local variable, its value is copied through the constructor created by the compiler. But is it true also for instance fields of the enclosing class like above? If yes, then the xxx instance could be garbage collected.

Please, put some light on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do a long running operation and use the date variable
    }
}
```

**within an instance method**, will produce an instance of an anonymous inner class that implements `Runnable`. Because the instance is of an inner class, it has a reference to the outer instance, the `XXX` instance.

The `Thread` which you `start()` will immediately start executing the `Runnable#run()` code in a new thread. As such, the `Runnable` cannot be GC'ed. Therefore any objects referenced by the `Runnable` instance cannot be GC'ed, ie. the `XXX` instance.

Comment: +1 The usual workaround is to create inner static classes to avoid the reference to a potentially very large enclosing class.

Comment: The bit about `Thread#target` is actually not important because the `run` method is the entry point of the thread. Clearly, the instance whose method is in execution is not eligible for GC.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik By being saved in the field, the `Runnable` is reachable. Since it's reachable, the enclosing instance is also reachable. Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 for the Thread#target, because that is what clears the entry point as well.

Comment: This is great explanation. And what about the date instance? It can not be GC'ed because it's referenced by the xxx instance, right?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But let's say it is not saved in the field. Is it then *unreachable*?---No, because `run` is executing therefore its `this` is on the stack as the first argument of the said `run` method. I am simply pointing out that there is no need to involve the internals of `Thread` when the matter is settled on the level of public API and specification.

Comment: @Behnil Right, it's a field of the `XXX` instance so it's not going anywhere.

Comment: In a way, it is even *wrong* to say that `Runnable` is reachable *because* of the reference inside `Thread`. That reference may be deleted via reflection, for example, and then your answer brings out the wrong conclusion.

Comment: +1 The Runnable will have a field called `this$0` which you can see in your debugger which refers to the outer class instance. BTW if you create a field called `this$0`, just to see what happens ;) you get a field called `this$$0`

Comment: @Marko Topolnik my question is about reachable state of the enclosing xxx instance, not the anonymous class instance. Or what are you talking about here? I'm a bit lost. Sotirios Delimanolis's answer is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Behnil Your `XXX` instance is reachable because the thread is executing your `Runnable` instance (it's on the method stack), not because `Thread` has a reference to the `Runnable` instance.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So I see what you mean, but this still has to do with the internals of `Thread` and threads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actually it doesn't: it has to do with the public specification which says that `run` will be executed on the new *thread of execution* (nothing to do with the `Thread` instance), the specified fact that an instance method has `this` at its disposal, and the specified fact that such a `this` is a GC root.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's why I said `Thread` _and_ `thread`, as in thread of execution.

Comment: But you said *iternals*, and I am not talking about internals. In fact, that is precisely my key point here: you are explaining publicly specified behavior via internals which may or may not be correct at all times, and are in any case irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik At this point, I don't mean internals in the sense of source code, but rather in the sense you were using to say that because the `Runnable` is actually being executed and is on the stack and because it has a `this` reference, and ..., etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

this process is an instance of an anonymous inner class that implements Runnable Interface. A pointer will be referenced to the `Thread#target` filed. Because of this instance, there is a DE-referencing and hence causes a problem. Java checks for point-able references before compilation. I tried compiling your code the class is easily accessible, so it need not be GC. And therefore, if you attempt creating a inner class you can avoid referencing to the instance of the outer or the enclosing class.

Comment: possible solution [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104538/java-anonymous-inner-class-life-cycle)

Answer (score 0):

```
   new Runnable() {
       @Override
     public void run() {
    // long running code separately using different value stack
    }
   }
```